# Indexing Stucks the xcode

Tags: xcode

Im using xcode 4.6 whenever I run the project the xcode stucks.This is because of indexing in the xcode.Indexing takes more time in my xcode.How to disable indexing in xcode.And i want to know whether any problem if I disable indexing.

Answer (score 1):

Indexing is "indexing" your code to make it searchable by xcode. The more in-depth answer is that indexing adds words, etc... to a data structure so you can search it quickly. Your machine is probably just slow, but you should let xcode index